# How to use JaCoCo Gradle Plugin with TestNG and JUnit?

Tags: gradle, junit, testng, jacoco, multi-module

I am working on a project where we are using TestNG and JUnit for our tests.

Unfortunately when writing TestNG tests they are not considered in JaCoCo Coverage Reports.

I wrote a `testng.gradle` file, which I include in each of the `build.gradle` files (it's a multi-module project):

```
task testNG(type: Test) { useTestNG() }
test.dependsOn testNG
```

Both JUnit and TestNG tests work this way.

If I write my `testng.gradle` like this:

```
test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

JaCoCo works properly, but obviously only TestNG tests get executed.

How can I fix it? Is it a bug in Gradle's JaCoCo plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems that while Gradle JaCoCo Plugin enhances `testNG` task, so that its execution uses [JaCoCo Java agent](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html), but it forgets to update `jacocoTestReport` task, so that this task doesn't use results of execution of `testNG` task. Don't know if this is a bug or on purpose, but solution is provided below.

#### to demonstrate this

file `src/main/java/Example.java`:

```
public class Example {
  public void junit() {
    System.out.println("JUnit");
  }

  public void testng() {
    System.out.println("TestNG");
  }
}
```

file `src/test/java/ExampleJUnitTest.java`:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleJUnitTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    new Example().junit();
  }
}
```

file `src/test/java/ExampleTestNGTest.java`:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ExampleTestNGTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    new Example().testng();
  }
}
```

file `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.8'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task testNG(type: Test) {
  useTestNG()
}

test {
  dependsOn testNG
}
```

After execution of `gradle clean test jacocoTestReport -d` you'll see in log

```
java ... -javaagent:.../jacocoagent.jar=destfile=build/jacoco/testNG.exec ...
...
java ... -javaagent:.../jacocoagent.jar=destfile=build/jacoco/test.exec ...
```

and that directory `build/jacoco` contains two files - `testNG.exec` and `test.exec`, for `testNG` and for `test` tasks respectively. While JaCoCo report shows only execution of JUnit by `test` task.

#### to solve this

Either instruct task `testNG` to write execution data into same file as `test`:

```
task testNG(type: Test) {
  useTestNG()
  jacoco {
    destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
  }
}
```

Either instruct task `jacocoTestReport` to also use `testNG.exec` file:

```
jacocoTestReport {
  executionData testNG
}
```

I'm assuming that the same should be done for the case of multi-module project in general and in your case in particular, since [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your multi-module project setup wasn't provided.

Comment: I have this same environment(testNG and jacoco) but this is not working for me.. I am always getting zero code coverage

Comment: On Gradle 6.6.1, the second solution worked for me, but I needed to also add `executionData testNG` inside the `jacocoTestCoverageVerification` config to get verification to stop failing when running `gradle check`. `jacocoTestReport` was picking up the correct code coverage data to build the report from the NG tests, but the verification task was still looking at the jUnit data. I'm not sure how to get it to pick up data from both jUnit and NG tests at the same time yet.

Answer (score 1):

The second solution from @Godin's fixed it for me. But to add on that, I found that `testNG` is not recognized by gradle since it is not matching the right *.exec file under `$buildDir/jacoco`. In my case it is `testNg.exec`, so it worked after I include this block in my subproject's build.gradle:

```
jacocoTestReport {
  executionData testNg
}
```

The first solution does not work for me

```
task testNG(type: Test) {
  useTestNG()
  jacoco {
    destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
  }
}
```

I guess it is because the testNG is overwriting the whole file `$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec` generated from JUnit.